# Getting exception on open of Show items from the following list popup

Tags: content-query-web-part

We am working on SharePoint 2010. We are getting bellow exception when we click browse button for Content Query Web Part > Show items from the following list

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.ObjectSerializer.evaluateTestAutomationId(CachedList cachedListToEval)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.ObjectSerializer.get_AutomationId()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.EcbEnabledTreeNode.RenderPreText(HtmlTextWriter writer)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer, Int32 position, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.RenderChildNodes(HtmlTextWriter writer, Int32 depth, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer, Int32 position, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)    
 at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)    
 at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)    
 at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)    
 at ASP._layouts_dialog_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\dialog.master:line 55    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

Check line 55 of your custom masterpage `dialog.master`. Seems like you're referencing something that returns `null`.

Comment: Hi Benny, Thanks for your hint. From where can i locate dialog.master? Is it from SPD?  I opened the file from file system at line number 55 there is below JS
var ok=(document.getElementById("<%= this.OkButton.ClientID %>"));

Comment: @shoab It's the fastest way to find your masterpage using SPD, but be careful - if you're planning on editing something in the masterpage - usa a better tool, such as Notepad++ or Visual Studio depending on preference and if the masterpage is deployed through a solution file. Does you're OK-button render OK without errors in the console [F12]?